# Video Indexer creates new containers every upload

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-video-indexer

In my Video Indexer, every time I upload a video I get these 3 different asset folders. When I upload 3 different videos, there will be 9 new asset containers. This is also the result when I use logic app. What could be the problem here? And what could be the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing are the Azure Media Services assets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/assets-concept

This is by design. If you want, you can build a process to delete them.

Comment: When I delete these assets, does it affect the videos I have uploaded in the Video Indexer?

Comment: Yes, for example, you won't be able to download, re-index and streaming.

Comment: Also, if you don't need streaming you can upload the video without streaming preset and you can save cost as well.

Comment: If its okay may I know to do that? I only want to upload videos and get the sentiments, I also don't need the assets container, what could be the ways to disable the creation of assets?

Comment: You can't avoid the assets creation. You can delete them after you get the content. Regarding the upload configuration you can set the indexingPreset in https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/api-details#api=Operations&operation=Upload-Video